# Spring Scheduler does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, scheduling

I have a problem with Spring's annotation based task scheduler - I can't get it working, I don't see any problem here...

application-context.xml

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler" />
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler" />
```

bean

```
@Service
public final class SchedulingTest {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SchedulingTest.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void test() {
        logger.debug(">>> Scheduled test service <<<");
    }

}
```

Comment: I get no errors and I expect to log the `>>> Scheduled test service <<<` message which doesn't happen...

Comment: is your logger configured properly, with the proper log level?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to use `task:annotation-driven` approach and your @Scheduled annotation is not working, then you most probably missed `context:component-scan` in your context xml. 
Without this line, spring cannot guess where to search for your annotations.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="..." />
```

Comment: Is there a spring-boot equivalent for the application.conf?

Answer (score 80):

[Spring @Configuration (non-xml configuration) for annotation-driven tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904956/spring-configuration-non-xml-configuration-for-annotation-driven-tasks)

Just add @EnableScheduling on your WebMvcConfig class

```java
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableAsync
    @EnableScheduling
    public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
       /** Annotations config Stuff ... **/
    }
```

Comment: adding @EnableScheduling saved my time a lot. Thanks very much

Answer (score 14):

This is happening because by default Spring lazy initializes the beans.

Disable lazy initialization for the bean by placing this annotation

```java
@Lazy(false)
```

on top of your `@Component`.

Answer (score 11):

For me the solution that worked in Spring 5 was that I had to add `@Component` to the class having `@Scheduled` annotated methods.

Answer (score 8):

After configuring the Schedulers, add **@EnableScheduling** in your main class.
[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution.

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="schedulingTest" class="...SchedulingTest" />

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="schedulingTest" method="test" cron="* * * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

and the `test()` method without the annotation. This runs the method every second and works perfectly.

Comment: This surely works since you leaved the `task:annotation-driven` approach. You my look at the other answer for the missing line. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

if you have dispatcher-servlet.xml move your configuration there. it worked for me and i have left a comment in this article:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11632536/546130

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to add in the applicationContext.xml:

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

with the following schemaLocation:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also check lazy-init to be false for that bean or use `default-lazy-init="false"` in beans.

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update my dispatcher-servlet.xml with

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd"></beans>
```

Bean definition below:

```
<bean id="scheduledTasks" class="com.vish.services.scheduler.ScheduledTasks"></bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the following reason:
Service needed an interface (due to Transaction annotation) - IDE added this tx annotation also to interface. But @Scheduled was in implementing service class - and Spring ignored it since it thought that only annotations exist on the interface. So be careful to only have annotations on implementing classes!

Answer (score 0):

Just add @EnableScheduling at any spring boot configuration class annotated with @Configuration and for the method that run the schedule job add @Scheduled annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for someone. I ran into similar issue when I had a bean that did a long processing job in PostConstruct method. Thus, Spring Boot application didn't start (because PostConstruct method was in progress) and that's why my scheduled jobs didn't run (they start running after application startup).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Grails with Spring Scheduler you will need to add to the top of your class.

```
static lazyInit = false
```

[Source](http://guides.grails.org/grails-scheduled/guide/index.html?utm_campaign=Groovy%2BCalamari&utm_medium=web&utm_source=Groovy_Calamari116)

Answer (score 0):

Add `@EnableScheduling` on top of `@SpringBootApplication` and you need to make sure your class with `@Scheduled` is marked with `@Service` or `@Component` annotation.